# Sync between two database on azure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, data-synchronization, sql-data-sync

I would like to ask a question how to setup azure syncing of two database on azure

i need real time data replication to the other database

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the Azure offering you want to use.

**Azure SQL Database**

You can get Geo-replication setup which is very straight forward and will give you a read-only secondary.

[Azure Portal : Geo replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-active-geo-replication-portal)

Azure SQL Managed Instance : You can use regular transaction replication (under preview) or geo-replication.

[Azure Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-auto-failover-group#best-practices-of-using-failover-groups-with-managed-instances)

Comment: Its just i want to replicate a production db to sand box db

Comment: A read-only replicated db from a Production will also fall into Production category. It is your way to offload some Production read work onto it. For a Sandbox, use a backup-restore to refresh your Sandbox.

Answer (score 2):

*Note: Since you tagged your question with Azure SQL Database, I assume this is the PAAS solution you are using.*

It depends on what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to read data from a readable secondary database or do you want a DR solution?

In Azure SQL Database there are 2 options to replicate your data: Read Scale-out and Active geo-Replication.

**Read Scale-Out** feature enables you to read data from read-only replica's instead of using the primary replica solely. This feature is enabled by default when you are using Premium, Business Critical or Hyperscale.
  When running on Basic, Standard or General Purpose you cannot use this feature since it uses a different high availability technology than Premium. Whereas Premium uses a technology similar to AlwayOn availability groups, standard uses a separated compute and storage layers. More information about the underlying architecture can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-high-availability).
Read Scale-out isn't a DR solution since all replicas are kept in the same DC. Synchronous commit is used to prevent data loss.
[More info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-read-scale-out)

**Active geo-replication** on the other hand allows you to create readable secondary databases in the same or different region(s). These databases must be of the same service tier, but apposed to Read scale-out, premium isn't required. You will only pay additional licensing cost for each secondary you add.
Asynchronous replication is used to prevent a performance hit on your primary database. Consequently, it's possible that there is some latency when reading from a replica, escpecially when this replica is hosted in another DC.
This can be used as a DR solution if you host your replica(s) in another DC.
[More info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-active-geo-replication)

Comment: Its just i want to replicate a production db to sand box db

Comment: And what would be the purpose of this sandbox? If it's for testing purposes I wouldn't use any form of replication or HA and just restore a copy of the database on a regular basis

Comment: yes its just for testing purposes only

Comment: Interesting! Regarding Read Scale-Out, do you have a source for "Synchronous commit is used to prevent data loss"? I've been looking for this info and would like to make sure.

Comment: What about **zone-redundant configuration** on the premium/buscrit tiers? Do they synchronously replicate to their same-datacenter secondary and asynchronously to the secondaries further away?

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to have two-way or one-way replication between two Azure SQL Databases then you can use [Azure SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data?wt.mc_id=MVP). It is free. You need consider one of the databases a hub and another database a member database. The member database can be another Azure SQL Database or a SQL Server instance (IaaS or on-premises). You can have many member databases.

The big disadvantage of this method is a 5 minute (or more) latency because the mimimum sync interval is 5 minutes.

If you want more information about SQL Data Sync visit [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/sync-sql-data-in-large-scale-using-azure-sql-data-sync/?wt.mc_id=MVP) article and if you want to go with this option please start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/scripts/sql-database-sync-data-between-sql-databases?wt.mc_id=MVP).

Comment: if i implement this azure sql data sync do i still have a way to execute "export data tier application"? and do you have some article or tutorial how to set up this step by step?

Comment: To export a database used by SQL Data Sync please read this https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Database-Support-Blog/Exporting-a-database-that-is-was-used-as-SQL-Data-Sync-metadata/ba-p/369062

Comment: You can use Azure portal to configure SQL Data Sync but you can also use PowerShell https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/scripts/sql-database-sync-data-between-sql-databases?wt.mc_id=MVP